# Select Column names from an array

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have created a string array which stores selected column names of sql server dataTable. I want to display records of selected column to a datagridview. I have created a temporary table 'dtTable' consisting of selected column name taken from the array. Then I have tried to use sql 'Select' to get the column names from 'dtTable' and get the record from my main table [Parameter Values]. Please note that column names are the same in both tables. But the number of columns are more in main table. The datagridview displays the dtTable column names correctly but no records are displayed. I think I a have problem in my sql command text. Here is my code:

```vb
''ParamName(10) is the string array that stores the selected column name
Dim dtTable As New DataTable
Dim SqlDataAdapter2 As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dr As SqlDataReader
For i = 0 To 9
    dtTable.Columns.Add(ParamName(i), GetType(String))
Next

Dim connStr As String = "Data Source= LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Main 
Data.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=60"
Dim conn As New SqlConnection(connStr)

Using conn
    conn.Open()
    SqlDataAdapter2.SelectCommand = cmd1
    Using cmd1
        cmd1.CommandText = "SELECT (SELECT COLUMN_NAME From INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

                    Where TABLE_NAME = N'dtTable')
                    FROM [Parameter Values]
                    WHERE [Record ID] > @ParamRowCount
                    And
                    [Project ID] = @ProjectID
                    ORDER BY [Record ID] ASC"
       cmd1.Connection = conn
       cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ParamRowCount", ParamRowCount)
       cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectID", ProjectID)
       dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader()

       If dr.HasRows = True Then
            dtTable.Load(dr)
        End If

        Me.dataGrid.DataSource = dtTable
    End Using
End Using
dr.Close()
```

Comment: Rel - don't use [addwithvalue](http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/)

Comment: Your query makes no sense to me. You are selecting from a table named "Parameter Values" but the only column you include is a subquery from the database metadata for a table named "dtTable". In theory that subquery should returned multiple rows which should generate an error - it will work only if that table contains a single column (which would be unusual). So I suggest you start over and discuss your goal.

Comment: i want to get rows of those columns only which are selected by the users. so i have taken those selected column names into an array and would like to get rows of those column from my main datatable. Please advise me,, what would be the sql command text?

Comment: You should build a dynamic TSQL statement that you would pass into SQL Server. The dynamic part is the name(s) of the columns. The challenge (and some reader's are already blowing up as they read this) is that you will have a lot of trouble protecting against people passing in somehow a SQL Server injection attack. Please look at how sp_execute SQL works and thats what I would use.